# Aberrant Flexbox behavior in Safari

Tags: css, safari, flexbox, mobile-safari

I ran into some weird flexbox behavior on safari and was hoping someone could explain it.
[Codepen of minimal example](https://codepen.io/danjruss/pen/XWmBXRX)

Snippet:

```css
// Culprits
// If any of these are removed, the strange behavior goes away {}
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0;
}

// Setup {}

.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.child {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

It works fine in Chrome and FF, but on safari, the `.child` collapses — presumably because of the `flex-grow: 0`. What's going on?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `flex: 0` on the `.child` element?

Comment: That’s a bit of a long story, and part of a very involved UI. I’ve found a workaround, now I’m trying to make sure I know why it was necessary.